# Confused regarding postMessage between sites

Tags: javascript, dom-events, cross-domain, messaging

I've uploaded an HTML containing the following section:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  window.addEventListener('message', receiver, false);
}

function receiver(event) {
  if (event.origin == 'http://documentA.com') {
    if (event.data == 'Hello B') {
      //event.source.postMessage('Hello A, how are you?', event.origin);
      alert("Recognized.");
    } else {
      //alert(event.data);
      alert("Unrecognized!");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The document is accessible and I can view it in the browser. Then, I open a console window using FireBug and type in the following call (as described [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging)).

```
window.postMessage("12345", "http://server:port/Index4.htm");
```

As a result I get *undefined* and frankly I have no clue if it's a good thing or a bad thing. Probably bad, especially since I don't get to see any *alerts*. What to do?

Comment: The result `undefined` just means, that `postMessage` does not return any value when you call it. It doesn't mean anything what can help you on debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first:

You have to post the message to the iframe. Try to use:

```
document.getElementById("yourIFrameID").contentWindow.postMessage()
```

---

---

I did the following in Opera Dragonfly, Firebug and IE9 and it works with no problems:

```
//Add iframe: <iframe id="teest" src="http://www.dict.cc/?s=annahme">
var frame = document.getElementById("teest")
```

Switch to iframe context:

```
//Add event listener
window.addEventListener("message", function(ev){ console.log(ev.data); }, false);
```

Back in the top-context, send some stuff:

```
frame.contentWindow.postMessage("foo", "http://www.dict.cc")
//Works. console: "foo"
frame.contentWindow.postMessage("foo", "http://www.dict.cc:80")
//Works. console: "foo"
frame.contentWindow.postMessage("foo", "http://www.dict.cc/?s=annahme")
//Works. console: "foo"
frame.contentWindow.postMessage("foo", "http://dict.cc/?s=annahme")
//Does NOT work. console: Nothing Happened
```

So, I see difficulties if you forget to add the right subdomain to the second parameter or if you visit a "https" page but have "http" in your string.
Try to remove all `if`'s in your event handler and print out what you get before using `if` (or even better inspect it with Firebug or Dragonfly)

Comment: cross-document messaging in IE seams to work only in iframes. See [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging)

Comment: @nameIsNull The questioner is actually working with IE but tests stuff in FF because he's too lazy to look for plug-ins he already has for the latter. :) Also, I'd like to learn a way to handle my issue in a browser-independent way and I'm hugely confused, so **any** hint is a good hint at this point.